# How to keep selected data in the table?

Tags: javascript, filtering, dc.js, crossfilter, data-processing

I have a logically single dimension I am interested in. I want to filter it using multiple filters - one in the graph and one in the text-select object. Here is [a sample](https://jsfiddle.net/ya5s4r9d/2/) and here is how it look like:

When text selectors only are used and then when we add selection on overview:
[image]
[image]

Note that **all text from selectors and table disappear**. How to make the text in at least the table to be  alive/visible? Or is it dc.js bug?

```
 var data = [{
      'name': 'c',
      'time': 0,
      'val': 1
    },
    {
      'name': 'c',
      'time': 1,
      'val': 7
    },
    {
      'name': 'b',
      'time': 0,
      'val': 2
    },
    {
      'name': 'b',
      'time': 1,
      'val': 3
    },
    {
      'name': 'a',
      'time': 0,
      'val': 4
    },
    {
      'name': 'a',
      'time': 1,
      'val': 5
    }
  ];

  var ndx = crossfilter(data);
  var runDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return [d.name, +d.time];
  });

  var run2Dimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return [d.name, d.time];
  });

  var run3Dimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return [d.name];
  });

  var runGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
  return +d.val;
});

  var select1 = dc.selectMenu('#test-select1');
  var select2 = dc.selectMenu('#test-select2');
  var overview = dc.seriesChart('#test-view');
  var focus = dc.seriesChart('#test-view2');
var datatable = dc.dataTable('#test-dt');


  select1
    .dimension(run3Dimension)
    .group(run3Dimension.group())
    .multiple(true)
    .numberVisible(10)
    .controlsUseVisibility(true);
  select2
    .dimension(run2Dimension)
    .group(run2Dimension.group())
    .multiple(true)
    .numberVisible(10)
    .controlsUseVisibility(true);

  datatable
    .dimension(run3Dimension)
    // Group table by
    //.section(function(d) {
    // return d.val;
    //})
    .columns(['name', 'time', 'val'])
    .size(data.length);

overview
  .width(768)
  .height(100)
  .chart(function(c) {
    return dc.lineChart(c).curve(d3.curveCardinal);
  })
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]))
  .brushOn(true)
  .xAxisLabel("Run")
  .clipPadding(10)
  .dimension(runDimension)
  .group(runGroup)
  .seriesAccessor(function(d) {
    return "Expt: " + d.key[0];
  })
  .keyAccessor(function(d) {
    return +d.key[1];
  })
  .valueAccessor(function(d) {
    return +d.value;
  });

focus
  .width(768)
  .height(480)
  .chart(function(c) {
    return dc.lineChart(c).curve(d3.curveCardinal).evadeDomainFilter(true);
  })
  .x(d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 20]))
  .brushOn(false)
  .yAxisLabel("Measured Speed km/s")
  .yAxisPadding("5%")
  .xAxisLabel("Run")
  .elasticY(true)
  .dimension(runDimension)
  .group(runGroup)
  .mouseZoomable(true)
  .rangeChart(overview)
  .seriesAccessor(function(d) {
    return "Expt: " + d.key[0];
  })
  .keyAccessor(function(d) {
    return +d.key[1];
  })
  .valueAccessor(function(d) {
    return +d.value;
  })
  .legend(dc.legend().x(350).y(350).itemHeight(13).gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(140).itemWidth(70));


  dc.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering on a series chart is tricky, because the data has 2D multi-keys and the brush has only one dimension, so the keys are incompatible.

If you want brushing to work in a series chart, you unfortunately need to use a different dimension that only includes the X axis.

IOW you would keep `runDimension` and `runGroup` the way they are but add another dimension, referencing the same column as the X dimension (`keyAccessor`):

```
var seriesFilterDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
  return +d.time;
});
```

Then set it in both the overview and focus chart. (It's a dc.js quirk that both will filter.)

```
overview
  .dimension(seriesFilterDim)
focus
  .dimension(seriesFilterDim)
```

Unfortunately, this means the chart will filter itself - points outside of the brush will drop to zero. I don't know any way around this, at least not without a complex reduction and a fake group to transform it into the multikey format required by the series chart.

[Fork of your fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/9krjyunv/9/).

As a side note, usually dimensions will return scalar (string/number) values. It is only appropriate to return arrays from the dimension key functions for scatter and series charts, and when using tag dimensions.

In particular your `run3Dimension` should be

```
  var run3Dimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.name;
  });
```

Comment: Nope - that change does not help to show anything on the table or in text  options when anything in overview is selected...(

Comment: Clearly I am tired. Forgot that you posted a fiddle, and wrote my answer without testing it. It's fixed now!